# Is there a way to make run a function every x th time a loop run - python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

let's say I have a loop that run over a list that contains numbers from 1 to 100 ( 100 element ), and I want to print i ( i is element in list  `for i in list:` ) every 25th time the loop runs so it after running it prints :
25
50
75
100

Answer (score 2):

Try the modulo operator "%" combined with a conditional:

```py
for x in range(101):
    if x%25 == 0:
        print(x)
```